# CSS make span sentence wrap on the same line?

Tags: css

```html
<span>Chat message:</span><span class="wrap">Chat message text WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</span>
```

The html above makes it appear like this:
[image]

But I want it to appear like this:

[image]

I've tried every wrap method I could find, `white-space` & `word-wrap`

Comment: You should probably show the CSS codes you've tried, so readers don't repeat them to you.

Comment: Guess you didn't try `word-break: break-all;` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```css
yourElementId {
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

The word-break property specifies how words should break when reaching the end of a line.

Does this help?